# With sudoers, how can I allow a user to change the group of files/folders within their home directory?

Tags: groups, sudo

I have a webserver where apache runs as www-data. Users are set up using chef, and some of their file/folder permissions are set to group: www-data, e.g. uploads folders.

Deployments are done with Capistrano, using the user account. It would be useful if during deployment, Capistrano could also change the group of files/folders to www-data.

How could I configure this, whilst maintaining security? I'm thinking an entry in the sudoers file that allows `<user>` to execute `chgrp www-data /home/<user>/*` whilst ensuring that the command does not contain `..`.

Comment: I would check out this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be best off writing a script and enabling that in sudoers. If your users will only ever need to run it on * within their homedir then something as simple as the following. It makes use of the SUDO_USER environment variable which you can find out more about here: http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html#environment

```
chgrp www-data /home/`echo $SUDO_USER`/*
```

I haven't tested this but it should work in principal.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll have to write a wrapper script as you say. the `*` was meaning *anything*, rather than specifically `*` in the command, so it's not possible to protect against `..` in the path, and symlinks pointing elsewhere on the system.

Comment: In the spirit of being over paranoid, would welcome any feedback on this - which is first draft to solve the problem - https://gist.github.com/colinbm/6507094